# Script for a 2stage login

Tags: python

Trying to make a script here that logins to www.marapets.com and then does some things (in this case refresh for a random event to happen and then activate it.) However they use a 2 step authentication and i cant figure out how to log in that way with python, does any of you know how to?

The script below should ne fully functioning on a 1stage login website.

Incase one of you guys want to test a script, the login details for an account on there are as follows;

username = "stackoverflow1"
password = "qwerty123456"

My script is as follows;

```
import sys,time,urllib,urllib2,cookielib,re,random,os
from datetime import datetime
caj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(caj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'),]
### User Details
username = "stackoverflow1"
password = "qwerty123456"
### CONSTANTS (Don't Touch)
LINK = "http://www.marapets.com/explore.php\?collect="


### COMPUTERS VARIABLES (Don't Touch)
regex = "<a href='"+LINK+"(.*?)'>"


### Functions
def GetUsernameFromID():
    url = "http://www.marapets.com/login.php"
    values = {'username' : username}
    strHTML = web(url,values)
    idMatch = re.compile("<input type='hidden' name='username' value='(.*?)'>")
    try:
        UserID = idMatch.findall(strHTML)
        return UserID[0]
    except:
        print "User does not exist.3124"
def Login():
    UserID = GetUsernameFromID()
    loginData = {'id' : UserID, 'password' : password}
    url = "http://www.marapets.com/dologin.php"
    if web(url,loginData) == "Bad Username":
        print "User does not exist.21"
    time.sleep(1)
def Regex(pattern,string):
    pattern = re.compile(pattern)
    try:
        return pattern.findall(string)
    except:
        return None

def web(url,values="none",update=0):
    try:
        global NewThread
        if values == "none":
            ## USE GET

            text = opener.open(url,timeout = 5).read()
            if text.find('Your account has been banned') > -1:
                print "This account is banned...."
                return
            return text
        else:
            ## USE POST
            data = urllib.urlencode(values)
            text = opener.open(url,data,timeout = 5).read()
            if text.find('Your account has been banned') > -1:
                print "This account is banned...."
                SetStatus("This account is banned.")
                return
            return text
    except ArithmeticError:
        print ""
    except Exception,e:
        print e
        print "Check Internet Connection/Proxy " + url
Login()
print "logged in"
i = 0
cake = 0
while 1:
    os.system("cls")
    print "Loop #",i+1
    print "Cakes:",cake
    webpage = web(random.choice(["http://www.marapets.com/atm.php","http://www.marapets.com/explore.php","http://www.marapets.com/news.php","http://www.marapets.com/giant.php"]))
    #print webpage
    try:
        link = Regex(regex,webpage)[0]
        HTML = web(LINK.replace("\\","")+link)
        print link
        if HTML.find("You opened") > -1:
            cake = cake + 1
    except Exception,e:
        print "No cake here"
    i = i + 1
```